# How to filter prometheus series based on the results of another query in grafana dashboard?

Tags: grafana

I am using Grafana 9.3.1 for monitoring of our system. Among other things, I am trying to monitor the remaining FUP of a phone number for each unit we operate.

Basically, we intend to use two data sources.

1. Database mapping of the unit ID to its phone number (e.g. `"unit_id=123, phone_number="00 123456789"`)
2. Prometheus time series `remaining_fup{phone_number="00 123456789"}`. However, `remaining_fup` is a 3rd party data and does not include `unit_id`.

In my unit-detail dashboard I have `unit_id` variable which indicates which unit FUP should be displayed (among other things depending on `unit_id`)

My original approach was this:

1. Create a mixed datasource dashboard
2. Add database datasource as data A. `SELECT phone_number FROM units WHERE unit_id='$unit_id'`
3. Add prometheus datasource `remaining_fup` and filter it based on `A.phone_number`:  `remaining_fup{phone_number="${A.phone_number}"}`

Unfortunatelly such use of `A` isn't supported. I used to hope for applying some transformation like Merge or Join by field and then Filter but with no success. After a lot of googling and trying I feel hopeless.

Could you help please? Is such filter even possible? Thanks!

TL;DR: In grafana dashboard I want to query one datasource in order to obtain a value which I subsequently want to use in another datasource query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) [Create variable](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/) - name `phone_number`, type: Query and query your database datasource `SELECT phone_number FROM units WHERE unit_id='$unit_id'`. You can hide this variable if you don't want it to be visible for the dashboard users.

2.) Variable `phone_number` may have multiple values, so use [advance variable formatting](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/variable-syntax/#advanced-variable-format-options/) to create valid regex query syntax for your prometheus datasource, e.g.

```
remaining_fup{phone_number=~"${phone_number:pipe}"}
```

Of course this queries are just examples and they may need some (syntax) tweaking for the use case. Main idea: don't use 2 queries, but one variable and one query (where you use that variable).